# How does the decimal accuracy of Python compare to that of C?

Tags: python, c, programming-languages, floating-accuracy, language-implementation

I was looking at the [Golden Ratio formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) for finding the nth Fibonacci number, and it made me curious.

I know Python handles arbitrarily large integers, but what sort of precision do you get with decimals? Is it just straight on top of a C double or something, or does it use a a more accurate modified implementation too? (Obviously not with arbitrary accuracy. ;D)

Comment: When you use the word "decimal" in the context of Python the usual assumption would be that you are referring to the `decimal` [library](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/decimal.html) which implements arbitrary precision arithmetic not at all comparable in accuracy to `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python floats use the double type of the underlying C compiler.  As Bwmat says, this is generally IEEE-754 double precision.

However if you need more precision than that you can use the Python [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) which was added in Python 2.4.

Python 2.6 also added the [fraction module](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) which may be a better fit for some problems.

Both of these are going to be slower than using the float type, but that is the price for more precision.

Answer (score 3):

almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

there's also the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) for arbitrary precision floating point math